# How to get the name of every npm package in the registry?

Tags: npm

I would like to get a list of every npm package name in the registry without mirroring the registry.

I tried hitting the listAll view (https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/blob/0134b24144ba1c445df9518523b6b448781da651/registry/views.js#L59-L61), but it times out (not surprised given that the registry is > 80gb).

Is there another api endpoint or service that could yield the dataset?

Comment: There is an approximation: https://github.com/zeke/all-the-package-names (hasn't been updated for a while)

Comment: @eush77 Though a little round-about, that could definitely suffice. I'd spin up a cron to call this once a day. I wonder how large the skimdb.json file would be on disk. Thanks a ton! I'll leave the question unanswered hoping for an actual endpoint.